# e keyCode does not work for me

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, keycode

I have a problem

My php file

```
<div id='1'><input type='text' onkeyup="comment('<?php echo $_SESSION["id"] ?>', e)"> 
</div>
```

My javascript file

```
function comment(id, e){alert(id); // WORK
alert(e.keyCode); //DOES NOT WORK}
```

Comment: why you are asking the same question again.Check the answers that you received earlier and if there is edits in the question then you should do it in that question not post same question again and again

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VA43k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
onkeyup="comment(event,'your string')"> 

function comment(e,id) {
  var comment = $(".blabla").val();
  // alert(message);  WORK
  alert(e.keyCode);
 }
```